# Unknown _TransactionIndex table in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Just noticed today that there is a random table in my Azure SQL Database that is named "_TransactionIndex_{guid}"

It has 1 column, Id, that contains 8 GUIDs.

Couldn't find any information about this table - what is it?  Does it mean that I have an issue with transactions within my application?

Comment: I don't know what the answer is but I have seen this table appear a few times in dbs I have imported from Bacpac files on Azure and each time the import has errored in some manner.

Answer (score 6):

It's an internal table that is used during the import of a `bacpac`. If all is well it should be gone when the import is done. If it remains in the database the import wasn't completed successfully.